# Set selected of a dynamic populated selectbox value ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `select` element that populates another `select` on change. Everything works fine, but I want to automatically set the value of the new `select` to the first item in the array.

```
$.get($(this).data('url'), { 
    option: $(this).val() 
}, function(data) {
    var subcat = $('#models');
    var options = " ";
    subcat.empty();
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        options += "<option value='" + element.id + "'>" + element.name + "</option>";
    });
    subcat.append(options);
});
```

What I want to do is to set the selected value of models to first item.

Comment: If the first element of the array is not been selected, then what element is been selected in the new selectbox?

Comment: How about: `$('#models').val(data[0].id)`

Comment: You should get this behaviour by default. If it's not occurring for you, then check that you're not setting the `val()` of the select somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Try `$('#models').val(data[0].id).change()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `option` variable is just a string, and you can't append a string like that to the `subcat` object and have it turn into `<option>`s automatically.

Instead try one of these methods inside your `$.each()` function:

```
subcat.append($("<option value='" + element.id + "'>" + element.name + "</option>"));
```

or:

```
subcat.append($("<option/>").val(element.id).text(element.name));
```

The first option should be selected by default.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc1539e4/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, i realized it was because i was using a select2 js. I de-activated it and your methods worked.